# Using a nested if to make spinner string conditional selections with a bottun using intent

Tags: android, if-statement, android-intent, android-spinner

I am a beginner and I want the user to select three fields from a spinner, and using conditional statements to test all the three fields with an if condition and the and operator to decide which activity to be started using a button and intent.

activity level_menu

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/choose_txt"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#ff000000"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/prog"
    android:textSize="32sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#ff000000"
    />
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/program_spinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:entries="@array/program_list"
    android:prompt="@string/programm_prompt"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30sp"
    android:backgroundTint="#e9ffc1"
    android:background="#e9ffc1" />

<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/lev"
android:textSize="32sp"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textColor="#ff000000"
/>
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/level_spinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30sp"
    android:backgroundTint="#e9ffc1"
    android:background="#e9ffc1" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/sem"
    android:textSize="32sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#ff000000"/>
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/sem_spinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:backgroundTint="#e9ffc1"
    android:background="#e9ffc1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"></Spinner>



<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnEnter"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/enter"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#ff000000"

    />
```

level_menu.java

```
package inc.zibit.com.conware;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;




public class Level_menu extends ActionBarActivity implements OnItemSelectedListener {
    private Spinner program_spinner;
    private Spinner level_spinner;
    private Spinner sem_spinner;
    private Button btnEnter;

    ArrayAdapter<String> program_adapter;
    List<String> program_list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.program_list)));

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_level_menu);

        addItemsOnSpinner2();
        addItemsOnSpinner3();
        addListenerOnButton();
     //   addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();

        program_spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.program_spinner);
        level_spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.level_spinner);
        sem_spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sem_spinner);
        program_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        level_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        sem_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);



        program_adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, program_list);
        program_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        program_spinner.setAdapter(program_adapter);
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if (!(program_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().trim().equals("Bsc. Computer Science"))) {

            if (level_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().trim().equals("Level 100")) {

                if (sem_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().trim().equals("1st Semester")) {

                    startActivity(new Intent(Level_menu.this, CompScience.class));

                }
            }
        }
    }
      @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }





    // add items into spinner dynamically
    public void addItemsOnSpinner2() {

        level_spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.level_spinner);
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Level 100");
        list.add("Level 200");
        list.add("Level 300");
        list.add("Level 400");
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        level_spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }
    public void addItemsOnSpinner3() {

        sem_spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.sem_spinner);
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("1st Semester");
        list.add("2nd Semester");
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sem_spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }


    public void addListenerOnButton() {
        btnEnter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEnter);

        btnEnter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if ( v.getId()==R.id.btnEnter){

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Level_menu.this,CompScience.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }

        });
    }
}
```

When i run it crashes.. what am I not doing right?

Comment: If it crashes, you need to post the logcat so we can see the exception/reason...

Answer (score 0):

Without any logs provided, my best guess would be that NullPointerException causes your crash inside onItemSelected() callback. If any of those 3 spinners have nothing selected, you will get NPE.

I suggest you first make sure that spinner.getSelectedItem() is not null, before comparing strings.

Comment: how do i make sure that the spinner.getSelecteditem() is not null

Comment: @CitizenZDc You can put an additional test inside if statements, something like:  `if (sem_spinner.getSelectedItem() != null && sem_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().trim().equals("1st Semester")) `. You can do the same for all 3 of those if statements, OR you can set a default selected item inside your spinners and avoid this problem altogether.